# File Upload Error in VuesJS Form and Rails 5.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form that is built with Vuejs in my Rails 5.1 app.  All my fields work well and persist data to the database, except for file uploads.  I get the error

`[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:` printed at the top of the console, then essentially my entire template code, then

`- <input v-model="variation.photo_one" type="file">:
File inputs are read only. Use a v-on:change listener instead.`

I am new to Vuejs and cannot figure out how to get this to work even after reading many other online posts regarding this.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= content_tag :div,
id: "product-form",
data: {
  id: product.id,
  product: product.to_json(except: [:id, :created_at, :updated_at]),
  variations_attributes: product.variations.to_json(except: [:product_id, :created_at, :updated_at]),
} do %>
 ...
    <div class="col-md-4 upload-block">
        <label>Photo One</label>  
        <input type="file" v-model="variation.photo_one" style="margin-bottom: .5em">
    </div>
    ...
<% end %>
```

**app_vue.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')

  var element = document.getElementById("product-form")
  if (element != null) {

    var id = element.dataset.id
    var product = JSON.parse(element.dataset.product)
    var variations_attributes = JSON.parse(element.dataset.variationsAttributes)
    variations_attributes.forEach(function(variation) { variation._destroy = null })
    product.variations_attributes = variations_attributes

    var app = new Vue({
      el: element,
      data: function() {
        return { id: id, product: product }
      },
      methods: {
        addVariation: function() {
          this.product.variations_attributes.push({
            id: null,
            name: "",
            photo_one: "",
            //position: "",
            _destroy: null
          })
        },

        removeVariation: function(index) {
          var variation = this.product.variations_attributes[index]

          if (variation.id == null) {
            this.product.variations_attributes.splice(index, 1)
          } else {
            this.product.variations_attributes[index]._destroy = "1"
          }
        },

        undoRemove: function(index) {
          this.product.variations_attributes[index]._destroy = null
        },

        saveProduct: function() {
          // Create a new product
          if (this.id == null) {
            this.$http.post('/products', { product: this.product }).then(response => {
              Turbolinks.visit(`/products/${response.body.id}`)
            }, response => {
              console.log(response)
            })

          // Edit an existing product
          } else {
            this.$http.put(`/products/${this.id}`, { product: this.product }).then(response => {
              Turbolinks.visit(`/products/${response.body.id}`)
            }, response => {
              console.log(response)
            })
          }
        },

        existingProduct: function() {
          return this.product.id != null
        }

      }
    })

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are a bit awkward in Vue. As the message says, you cannot use `v-model` for an input with `type="file"`. Instead you must use the `change` event and call a method in your component to manually handle the file.

```
<input type="file" @change="handleFileChange" />

methods: {
    handleFileChange(event) {
        //you can access the file in using event.target.files[0]
        this.fileField = event.target.files[0];
    }
}
```

When you submit the AJAX request, you will likely need to submit a `FormData` object instead of submitting a javascript object. The MDN docs have an explanation on how to use that. I find the FormData is the more awkward part of dealing with file uploads. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData